# Swift - Dependency compile errors

Tags: swift, xcode, compilation, cocoapods

I produced my app using Xcode 9 beta. I now regret this choice.

I tried to upload to the App Store and was told I couldn't with beta software, so I have downloaded Xcode 8.3.3.

In my app I use a CircularSlider pod framework, [here](https://github.com/taglia3/CircularSlider)

When I compile with Xcode 8.3.3 I get the error that the

> dependancy Swift Version is required to be configured correctly

When I go to the Pod swift version it is currently on Swift 4 (Unsupported). I never set it to this.

**On my Xcode 9 file it is set to 3.2.**

The only other option in 8.3.3 that I can change this too is Swift 3 or Unspecified.

Setting it to swift 3 creates loads of errors.

What can I do about this issue? Why can I not set the pods Swift Language version to 3.2

Comment: Setting the pods to Swift 4 seems to be a Cocoapod bug. You need to go to each of the pods and set it back to Swift 3.2. The clean you derived data, and restart XCode. Should be ok then

Comment: Beta versions of Xocde will never be allowed for uploads to Appstore

Comment: No matter what I try I get the same error: “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Comment: You should be getting the error for a particular Pod are you updating the build setting of the Pod and not that of the Target project?. Try deleting all the pods and do a pod install again. I Know I had the error but cannot remember the exact sequence of remedies I used

Comment: Here is a link on the subject https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6791

Comment: Its weird. Awful bug. I just kept doing it over and over and over again. Eventually got there. Thanks all.